# Microsoft Dynamics CRM storage options for attachments

Tags: blob, dynamics-crm, attachment, dynamics-crm-4

MS Dynamics CRM stores attachments as annotations(notes) in BLOB format.  Is there any way to store attachments in the file store?  Perhaps an alternate way to upload attachments instead of storing them as blobs in the database?

We have a requirement to migrate data from an application from another platform, and there are a lot of PDF and Word files which makes importing to the CRM database unfeasible.

Answer (score 1):

You can import that files in "File Hosting Services sites"(Eg. Drop box , Amazon S3) and retrieve the Url from it and migrate that URL in CRM related entity custom field.

Answer (score 0):

Well CRM has an integration with SharePoint which seems like a good place to start.

Failing that you could use another document container (or build your own) and then integrate it with CRM.